# Passing runtime parameter to JAR in DockerFile not running

Tags: java, docker, jar

Dockerfile:

```
FROM anapsix/alpine-java
ADD abc-server-application.jar abc-server-application.jar
EXPOSE 9199

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Dkafka_delay_time=20","-DlogsInclude=docker-logback.xml","-jar","abc-server-application.jar"]
```

In `/home/user/abc` - I have placed the JAR and the Dockerfile and docker-logback.xml file

Build Image:

```
[root@CP9909abc#]docker build -t abc-server-application:v1.0 .
```

Run:

8090 is the port configured in application.yml

```
[root@CP9909abc#]docker run -p 9199:8090 abc-server-application:v1.0 -it /bin/bash &
```

Now, application is not running. It gives message like -

> ch.qos.logback.core.joran.util.ConfigurationWatchListUtil@277050dc -
>   Adding [file:/docker-logback.xml] to configuration watch list.
>   12:36:51,898 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.IncludeAction
>   - Failed to open [file:/docker-logback.xml] 12:36:51,898 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of
>   configuration.

In entrypoint, I tried giving absolute path/relative path for docker-logback.xml but it's not working. Any Suggestions on how should I pass the log back file to JAR in Docker?

Comment: Your Java application is receiving arguments `-it /bin/bash`; is that causing this error?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the `docker-logback.xml` getting copied using the Dockerfile also there is no volume mount. Copy it using below statement & then try to run the image -

```
FROM anapsix/alpine-java
ADD abc-server-application.jar abc-server-application.jar
COPY docker-logback.xml ./
EXPOSE 9199
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Dkafka_delay_time=20","-DlogsInclude=docker-logback.xml","-jar","abc-server-application.jar"]
```